# VB - how to link up a Check_change to code behind for a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

How do I enable a check_change for a checkbox in VB.

Here is what I have so far.

Code Behind:

```
    Protected Sub CheckBoxCash_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxCash.CheckedChanged
        Label1.Text = "Cash"
    End Sub
```

Front end code:

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Empty"></asp:Label>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPoints" runat="server" Checked="True" />
```

Comment: Coincidence or not: Your VB method `Handles CheckBoxCash.CheckedChanged`, but your checkbox name is `CheckBoxPoints`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not doing anything that specifically requires a postback here.  In that case, I'd skip the postback entirely an do it more like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Empty"></asp:Label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPoints" runat="server" Checked="True" onclick="document.getElementById('Label1').value = 'Cash';" />
```

Of course, that's the simple version.  Production code would also involve checking the label's clientid property in case these controls ever end up inside a naming container (like an asp:panel or gridview).  I'd also look for a fallback for when javascript is not enabled, but in this case the Check_Changed server event depends on javascript to fire anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,  I forgot to set the postback to true